# Customers that only made one order

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I'm looking to write a SQL Query to get the Customers that made only one order after the first of March. So if they ordered twice after the first of March I want to exclude them.

I have the following data extensions.

**MainDE**

CustomerID(PK)

FirstOrderDate(null)

**OrdersDE** (this is the DE with all orderes so if a Customer would have ordered on the first of March and second of March would be two orderDates)

CustomerID(PK)

OrderHeaderID(PK)

OrderDate(null)

I have created a third DE with the following fields

**MyDE**

CustomerID(null)

FirstOrderDate(null)

OrderDate(null)

This is what I have so far

```
SELECT
a.customerID,
a.FirstOrderDate,
b.OrderDate

from [MainDE] a

left join [OrdersDE] b
on a.customerID = b.customerID 

and [FirstOrderDate] > DATEADD(hh, 7, '01 March 2020')
```

Comment: Have you tried adding something like `where count(b.customerID) = 1`?

Comment: sorry @zuzannamj, not sure if I understand. How would that help?

Comment: You would need something like GROUP BY a.customerID HAVING COUNT(a.customerID) = 1

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

I recreated your scenario:

[image]

And used this query:

**select customerid,orderdate,orderheaderid from orders where customerid in (
SELECT
customerid
from orders
group by customerid
having count(customerid) = 1
) 
and FORMAT(orderdate, 'mm-dd-yyyy') = FORMAT(cast('03-01-2020' as date), 'mm-dd-yyyy')**
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not getting the expected result, not sure why because in your recreated scenario the output looks right. I'm getting 136 records and I should be getting around 70k

Comment: Can you share your query? Also, can you share your data extension structure, just want to see the primary keys and data types,if that's OK.

Comment: My query is a copy paste from yours. The PK for the order table is a composite key with CustomerID(number)(PK) and HeaderID(number)(PK) and the order date is null.

Comment: Can you check how many customers have purchased just once, by running the internal query?

Comment: I just looked at the dates and noticed that with your query I only get the customers who ordered once but on the first date of the month so 1st of march, 1st of april and 1st of may

Comment: Is is not your requirement, to include people who have purchased on 1st March only?

Comment: no, my requirements is to get the people who only ordered once from the 1st of March as the first order date onwards

Comment: select customerid,orderdate,orderheaderid from orders where customerid in ( SELECT customerid from orders group by customerid having count(customerid) = 1 ) and FORMAT(orderdate, 'mm-dd-yyyy') > FORMAT(cast('03-01-2020' as date), 'mm-dd-yyyy')

Comment: You can try the above query :)